# ftp to show files with owner on linux

Tags: linux, ftp-client, suse

We used to get directory content listed with the owner name from HP-UX system using  FTP client , recently the system was migrated to Suse-Linux. Now when we FTP to this machine, directory list does not show the owner name of the files.

How would one enable listing directory with owner name in Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

Well in `ftp` (and most shells anyway), you have the `ls` command. This prints the list of files.

```
**Example session** (cutted out some messages):

$ ftp ftp.ed.ac.uk
Connected to luther.is.ed.ac.uk.
220-

 Login using the username 'anonymous' and use your email address as password.

ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            8 Feb 26  2014 INSTRUCTIONS-FOR-USING-THIS-SERVICE -> .message
drwx-wx-wx   3 root     root         4096 Feb 17 14:57 edupload
drwx-wx-wx   3 root     root       131072 Feb 17 20:20 incoming
drwxr-xr-x  45 root     root         4096 Feb 19  2014 pub
226 Transfer complete
ftp>
```

The table shows:

- `drwxdrwxdrwx`: `d` stands for directory, and then `rwx` for read-write-execute for (in sequential order), the owner, the group and all people with login access;
- the name of the owner (`root`);
- the name of the group of the owner (`root`);
- file size;
- modification date; and
- filename.

Comment: The problem was the way FTP server was configured. Nothing to do with ls. dir command on FTP client was showing owner id, not the owner name. The Sysadmin told me that he had to insert some variable in the ftp.config.

Comment: @TonyP: you don't call `ls` you call the `ls` command **of** `ftp`.